# iframe alternative for loading unknown user generated content into a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iframe

I am pretty sure there is not an alternative, but maybe i am missing something.

I have a page (mobile, but does not matter ) and on that page , when the user clicks on a link it loads the div (currently by iframe )

The reason i use an iframe, is because most of the html being loaded is from external sites or user generated content that relies on the external CSS.

So i all the articles i find say load using ajax. Thats pretty easy to do, but when i load via ajax it is going to load all the page html (header, body etc. ) into the div. I assume this is still going to use my css (if there are generic styings)

I am pretty sure iframe is the way to do it, but that creates its own problems with mobile and widths

thanks for any help

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can stay with the Iframe solution and on load adjust the content.
Or use the ajax and again, parse the HTML as you wish. Remove unnecessary elements.